getting error while install express in vs code
I have been getting this error while trying to install express.

PS C:\Users\Dell - i5\Desktop\starter> npm i express
(node:5044) [DEP0170] DeprecationWarning: The URL http://proxy-server-address:port is invalid. Future versions of Node.js will throw an error.
(Use node --trace-deprecation ... to show where the warning was created)
npm error code ERR_INVALID_URL
npm error Invalid URL
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Dell - i5\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-10-29T23_03_27_807Z-debug-0.log

I have tried every solution and watching videos on youtube but still to no avail

There must be http-proxy setting enabled. You need to disable this both locally and globally.Only then you can install express without any issue.

This question is similar to: The URL http://proxy-server:port is invalid. Future versions of Node.js will throw an error. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
